# Is it possible to create a Java App that can open two different user profiles?

Tags: java-me

A question for all who consider themselves somewhat experienced in Java apps for mobile.
 Is it possible to create a Java App that can open two different user profiles, for instance if I were to turn the phone on, this app would ask for a password. Depending on the password the phone would then direct me to one of two user profiles a master profile and a less dominant one (guest), to where the master profile doesn't share any files or contact info with the guest profile. Is this just a fantasy, a possibility or reality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a fantasy. Java ME doesn't have any rights to do all of this.
And J2ME MIDlets can't add themselves to startup.

Comment: By "profiles" I simply mean a user. Similar to the concept windows uses with their Administrator User and Guest Users.
Furthermore, If an application is not what Im looking for, you have any suggestions?

Comment: This is impossible to do on simple mobile phone. Maybe it's possible on Symbian mobile phone, but even if it was possible, it would be very hard.

Comment: So there is no possible OS or similar app that does something close to what Im asking?

Comment: Even if I was using this for a generic iPhone?

Comment: I don't know about iPhone, but I'm almost sure it's also impossible there.